# How can I observe the effect of SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL off?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclient

We have an old database product; the master deployment has always done `ALTER Database [databasename] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`. Since this setting is going away, we want to come up with a testing plan for getting rid of it and tracking down what code depends on it.

With this switch off, the documentation says that `SELECT 'abc' + NULL FROM sometable` results in abc rather than NULL.

I can easily observe this behavior at the connection level; however the application *never* sets it at the connection level. That's not the question here.

How can I observe by any SQL statement the effect of turning off `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` only at the database level using .NET `System.Data.SqlClient` as the database access client?

We audited the entire codebase and removed all instances of SET commands except for transaction isolation level as these hose things pretty hard. While I tried `EXEC` to see if it would bypass the driver settings and found it didn't, I'm reasonably certain there's some sufficiently exotic SQL construction that could succeed.

Comment: Do you want to search all query in database which will be affected by  on `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` ? Frankly it is not clear to me.Can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: @KumstHarsh: I want to search all queries for constructs that ignore the dbc driver setting of ON and thereby cause the DB setting to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have finally understood what you actually want: to change the connection option without changing it. **No, there are no ways to achieve this**, otherwise I would have heard about them, and Rutzky would have mentioned them in his answer I referenced in my original response.

There is a strict hierarchy in a way the options can be set:

1. Instance-wide settings for all databases, using `sp_configure 'user options'`. Lowest level defaults.
2. Database-specific options which can be set via `ALTER DATABASE`. Take precedence over instance defaults.
3. Explicit `SET` statements executed on the connection. Override everything.

The advice? Change the application' connection string, if you can, so that it would use another driver that doesn't set / touch this option. Assuming, of course, it wouldn't crash anything, but this is a thing which can be tested relatively quickly.

Also, you may try to change the instance defaults, and see if the driver somehow favours them over #2. It is possible that it can be too smart for its own good.

---

P.S. For the sake of completeness, the only cases of interdependent options that I know of are listed below:

1. Shortcut settings, for example `ANSI_DEFAULTS`. Setting it actually affects several options related to ANSI compatibility;
2. `SET LANGUAGE`. When you change the connection language, it also overrides the `DATEFIRST` and `DATEFORMAT` options.

---

P.P.S. I decided to leave my previous answer intact, as it still contains some info which might be useful for people who would understand your question the way I initially did.

Comment: Ok so I got the rest of the story finally. A long time ago, parts of this .NET application would use COM's CreateObject to create the VB6 connection driver, which didn't turn on SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL automatically, leaving me this crazy thing left around to find.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your application doesn't specify this option explicitly, different ODBC and OLEDB drivers have different defaults for connection options. Depending on the driver, this particular option can either be set implicitly, or inherited from database / server settings.

In order to see the actual state of this option for connections established by your app, you can [setup a Profiler trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/create-a-trace-sql-server-profiler) which will show you effective connection settings.

In regards to overriding the driver's behaviour setting this option, there is a rather [thorough answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95090/48699) for a similar question on DBA StackExchange. There, you can find several possible approaches, and see which one suits you best.

On the SQL side, one possible solution is to replace old style `+` string concatenations with the newer `concat()` function which is available since SQL Server 2012. This function skips `NULL` arguments during concatenation, so the result always looks as if `concat_null_yields_null` is set to `off`. Depending on the amount of SQL code modules in your system, it might be quite an undertaking, especially as it's difficult to distinguish between numerical additions and string concatenations with a naked eye.

I would recommend to shop around for some code analysis / refactoring tools that might lend a hand in this. Not sure if SSDT has this capability, but I would start with it first, since it's free (and it might make sense to try out the Visual Studio 2019, which was released 2 days ago - there might be something there). Other than that, well... RedGate, Idera, ApexSQL, you name it. Someone might have done this already.

Comment: I had figured out the driver is changing it. Do you know any case where the connection data is discarded?

Comment: @Joshua, updated the answer with a link to a similar question and possible solutions.

Comment: Ah; not a bad link. The question is more or less what could cause the driver behavior to change besides a SET command. (I had to track down and remove all the SET commands long ago because their state leaks across the pool.

Comment: @Joshua, an update, either of the driver itself, or some libraries coming with a new service pack and / or another Windows release. It might be documented somewhere, but I've never come across such references.

Comment: The point of your confusion finally occurred to me. I'm not trying to find which one suits me best. I'm trying to enumerate all remotely plausible ways and _remove them_ by code audit.

Comment: @Joshua, I see. Updated the answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: Oops dropped your bounty on the wrong answer by you. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with this query

```
IF (SELECT ''+NULL) IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
END
```

Comment: Use of SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL explicitly is excluded from the question.